# Creating a log script

Tags: php, database, email, logging, outlook

I would like to create a log in the Database everytime i send or receive an email. I need to receive an event from outlook everytime an email is sent or a contact is created. The server is a LINUX server on Amazon https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2017.09-release-notes/

The code that I have tried so far is as below.

```
function wh_log($log_msg)
{
    $log_filename = "log";
    if (!file_exists($log_filename)) 
    {
        mkdir($log_filename, 0777, true);
    }
    $log_file_data = $log_filename.'/log_' . date('d-M-Y') . '.log';
    file_put_contents($log_file_data, $log_msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Its not working.
May I know what am I doing in-correct?

Comment: So are you saying that you are NOT receiving the event from OutLook or this code is not writing to the file?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Logs are not created when I receive an event from outlook everytime an email is sent or a contact is created

Comment: So how do you call this function?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Just added on the AWS backend.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct!

I would do a constant for the log folder name.
Then, I would also write the log filename with year, month and day, so that it is sorted alphabetically.

This code works on my computer:

```php
<?php

define('LOG_FOLDER', '/var/log/my_php_app');

function wh_log($log_msg)
{
    if (!file_exists(LOG_FOLDER)) {
        if (!@mkdir(LOG_FOLDER, 0775, true)) {
            die('Cannot create the log folder!');
        }
    }
    $log_filename = LOG_FOLDER .'/log_' . date('Y-m-d') . '.log';
    file_put_contents($log_filename, $log_msg . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}


wh_log('Starting the script');

sleep(1);

wh_log('Finished!');
```

Did you check that the folder where the `log` folder will be created has write permission?

Better check the result value of `mkdir()` before continuing. Here I brutaly stop the PHP script (which is not the best thing to do, but it's just for the example).

Check your PHP error log to see if you can get more information on what is going wrong.

I expect your PHP code is running with a specific user account and group. It could be `www-data`, `apache` or a specific account user. This depends on the hosting. I usually create the log folders in advance when deploying the website. The folder itself should have *read*, *write* (and could also have *list* if needed) for the PHP user or group.

Typically I would do this in a terminal:

```sh
sudo mkdir /var/log/my_php_app
sudo chown root:www-data /var/log/my_php_app
sudo chmod ug=rwx,o=rx /var/log/my_php_app/
```

Comment: Thank Patrick for the answer. I have to check your code and see if it works fine for me or not. +1 for the effort.

Comment: @Nitesh You're welcome! I also replaced the 0777 by 0775, so that other users cannot write in your log folder.

Comment: I dont see anything of any note that actually changed in this code from the orignal

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, you're right! I added a comment about write permissions in the parent folder where the `log` folder has to be created.

Comment: So how will that solve the OP's issue of Not getting the file written?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the comment! I edited by adding a check of the `mkdir()` result as I expect this might be the main problem.